# objects not showing in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, visibility

some objects arent showing up in the final render and i have no idea why. they used to and they just decided not to. (ignore the windows in the final render image i used a jpg)

materials will be missing because [the blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oyiL9Amry4la-Pnkl6sJjPWjkUO5tp0d/view?usp=sharing) is already about 75mb and i dont want to make it much larger

[image]
[image]

Comment: Outliner > Carpet > Plane.001 excluded from Global Viewport, but not from Rendering (Camera Icon).

Comment: oh my gosh thank you i would have never found that

Comment: You would :) There is not other than try&fail process ... especially if you have something in Viewport render and not in final Render there is almost 99% chance that there is a mismatch in Outliner setting. You have to disable half of collections nad see if issue persists. If not, han the issue is in second group of collections. Like that half by half you will find the issue collection. Than just open hierarchy and check what is is off in Viewport and on in Render. It is very often issue here ... just practice :)